# Callback завершения плавного перемещения Яндекс Карты API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача: по какому-то событию (в примере - клик по карте) запускать плавное перемещение карты, а после его завершения вызывать заданную callback функцию. Есть ли возможность поставить callback на завершение анимации плавного перемещения карты?

```
initMap();
async function initMap() {
  await ymaps3.ready;
  const {YMap,YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,YMapListener}=ymaps3;
  const map=new YMap(document.getElementById('map1'),{location:{center:[37.617134,55.755793],zoom:8}});
  map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());

  function onMoveComplete() {
    alert('OK');
  }

  function onMapClick(object,event) {
    map.update({location:{center:event.coordinates,duration:3000}}); // callback:onMoveComplete?
  }

  const mapListener=new YMapListener({
    layer:'any',
    onFastClick:onMapClick,
  });
  map.addChild(mapListener);
}
```

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Map - событие actionend

Comment: Я использую версию API 3, там как-то по-другому всё делается... Попробовал повесить onActionEnd в слушателя карты, но он вызывается при сдвиге карты мышкой и зуме колесом, но не вызывается там, где надо - после окончания сдвига, запущенного скриптом.

Comment: Тогда в том же скрипте, который запускает анимацию, можно запустить нужную функцию с таймаутом 3000 или чуть больше, раз время анимации известно.

Comment: Да, в принципе, вариант, спасибо.